# How to get a bundler enabled rails app running as a service with upstart?

Tags: upstart, ruby, rails

I can get some random shell script to run as a service...that's not the problem.  I think it's related to environment variables given some of the google-ing I did.  Either a list of required rails environment variables or a sample rails app running as a service would be helpful.

I found this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/327965/how-to-start-a-rake-task-using-upstart
Which is helpful, but it incorporates rvm.  I like rvm, but I'm looking for a way to do it without this additional bit of complexity.  I may be forced to do it that way though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `bundle install --deployment --binstubs` make sure you create a stub `bin/bundle` (Bundler does not do this).  Then in `/etc/init/your-app.conf`:

```
start on started network-services
stop on stopping network-services

<set env variables you need>

script
pushd <Your app's Gemfile folder>
bin/bundle exec ....
end script
```

After that, you have to run

```
initctl reload-configuration
```

That should do it.

Comment: upvote.  after i verify it working in my implementation i'll give it the check

Comment: The solution of hedgehog is working fine, but maybe it's worth mentioning that 1. After adding the `.conf` script to `/etc/init` you have to run `initctl reload-configuration` (sorry I'm a newb and didn't know this) 2. the `pushd` command threw an error in the corresponding log file `/var/log/upstart/SERVICE.log` and I had to use `cd` instead (don't know, if this is "bad")